# Can a Prusa be converted to IDEX?

Tags: prusa-i3, dual-nozzle

I have a Prusa i3 Mk3s with an MMU2s on it. And to be frank, as far as the MMU goes, I have not had much luck with it.  I've seen people print amazing MMU prints and it works great for them, but I have had MUCH less success.

If a print requires 900 filament changes to go back and forth between colors, even if I have the MMU dialed-in to work 99 % of the time, well that's still 9 failures in that print. I'm sure there are things I could do to dial it in, but I have a different question for now:

I have other printers I work with that have dual extruders and work great, and I've been eyeballing an IDEX kit for my Ender 3, which got me thinking that there's gotta be a way to put IDEX on a Prusa.

I was also eyeballing my MMU and thinking I could scrap it for parts (stepper motors etc) for the IDEX.  I did a quick Google search and couldn't really find anything, but is there a reason for that?  Is the control board not able to handle it, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would require an adaptation so extensive that I would define it "rebuild".

You would end up savaging basically only the bare frame and the steppers.

I'm not aware, in fact, of anyone ever doing it.